# ubuntu server vs desktop edition

Tags: ubuntu, desktop

I have a dilemma of selecting between ubuntu edition for development server.
I have seen that ubuntu server dosen't have a GUI(though can be installed later).
My question :
is there any specific difference in desktop and server edition that will help in development of web app?

Comment: This is off-topic by the current criteria for SO.  Probably the best alternative (now) would be http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The server edition of Ubuntu is really intended to be run if you have racks of server machines on which you are deploying your application. If you are actually using this machine for development purposes, then you should simply use the regular distribution of Ubuntu instead of the server edition. That said, the only real difference is the default software; you can easily convert a server edition to an identical regular edition or vice-versa by installing/uninstalling the associated packages with the apt-get commands.

Comment: thanks, what I needed to know as well. points to you

Comment: Just to be clear here, by the _associated packages_ do you mean [`ubuntu-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-desktop) ?

Answer (score 2):

Anything you will not get by default in either version can be added. If you want a GUI then going with desktop will probably be easier in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between the desktop and server editions is the packages installed by default.  The server edition is pretty bare, whereas the desktop edition has a bunch of packages installed.

Answer (score 1):

apart from the difference on pre-installed packages, some of the configuration scripts are also different. Ubuntu server configuration follows the same logic as the other distributions were as Ubuntu desktop is modified to become easier to be configured by an end user. For example take a look at the link below for an example on configuration of `inittab`:

http://nixcraft.com/linux-software/2654-ubuntu-set-default-runlevel-etc-inittab.html

Answer (score 0):

*Ubuntu Server is shipped with already installed server tools but it's not user-friendly.

*Ubuntu Desktop is for regular and home users with nice GUI and display and shipped with basic tools.